# Can I access the cube/perspective name within SSAS tabular through DAX?

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular

Within DAX in SSAS Tabular, I would like to alter the behaviour of a measure depending on the name of the Perspective...

Is it possible to find out the name of the perspective within DAX?

PS: What I am trying to do is to hide some measure if the perspective name is not a specidfic value.
And I want the measure to be hidden in the default perspective...

Comment: The point of a perspective is to hide tables, columns, and measures. Why not just hide the measure in the perspective?

Comment: Because I need the measure hidden in the default perspective and made visible in the "new" perspective.
Rather than the other way round

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found another way to achieve the intended behaviour.

I can use the CUSTOMDATA() DAX function to check for a specific value passed through the connection string. If I don't see that value my measures do something, otherwise they do something else.

It is not using perspectives but extremely similar because it is actioned by a specific detail of the connection string, like a perspective in fact